# Dropping index in DataFrame for CSV file

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

Working with a CSV file in PyCharm. I want to delete the automatically-generated index column.  When I print it, however, the answer I get in the terminal is "None".  All the answers by other users indicate that the reset_index method should work.

If I just say "df = df.reset_index(drop=True)" it does not delete the column, either.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("music.csv")
df['id'] = df.index + 1
cols = list(df.columns.values)
df = df[[cols[-1]]+cols[:3]]
df = df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
print(df)
```

Comment: You cannot delete the index in a pandas dataframe

Comment: `reset_index(drop=True)` is typically used when after sorting a dataframe you wish to drop the original index. `reset_index` itself resets the index to match the newly sorted items.

Answer (score 1):

`index_col=0` can work if `index_col=None` or `index_col=False` si. 
So do like this when reading a file if you want to drop the unwanted index column.
`df = pd.read_csv('filename.csv', index_col=0)`

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @It_is_Chris. Also,

This is not true because return is None:

`df = df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)`

It's should be like this:

`df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)`

or

`df = df.reset_index(drop=True)`

Answer (score 0):

Since you said you're trying to `"delete the automatically-generated index column"` I could think of two solutions!

Fist solution:

Assign the index column to your dataset index column. Let's say your dataset has already been indexed/numbered, then you could do something like this:

```
#assuming your first column in the dataset is your index column which has the index number of zero  
df = pd.read_csv("yourfile.csv", index_col=0)

#you won't see the automatically-generated index column anymore
df.head()
```

Second solution:

You could delete it in the final csv:

```
#To export your df to a csv without the automatically-generated index column
df.to_csv("yourfile.csv", index=False)
```